# How to call get API with passing header and body without streamed response in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, get, stream, flutter-streambuilder

Here is my code. I'm not able to store streamed responses in model,
so I want response in any other manner, or I want solution for how to store response in model.

```
List<dynamic> dataList = [];
StreamController<List> dataC = StreamController();
var headers = {
  'CustomAuthentication': '',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'cookie'
};

var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('url'));
request.body = json.encode({ "data_value": "val" });
request.headers.addAll(headers);
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
//print(response.stream.toString());
if (response.statusCode == 200)
{
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
  dataList.add(response.stream.bytesToString());
  dataC.add(dataList);
  for(int i=0; i<dataList.length; i++) {
    print(dataList[i].toString());
  }
  print(dataList[0].toString());
}
else { print(response.reasonPhrase); }
return response.stream.bytesToString();
```

Comment: and why don't you use `http.get` / `http.post` etc instead?

Comment: in that i can't add body

Comment: yes, you can: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/put.html optional param: `Object? body`

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```
 Future<void> fetchData() async {
   
      // Define your headers
      final headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer your_token',
      };
      
      // Define your request body
      final body = jsonEncode({
        'param1': 'value1',
        'param2': 'value2',
      });

      final uri = Uri.https('www.myurl.com', '/api/v1/test', body);
      
      try {
        final response = await http.get(
          url,
          headers: headers,
        );
        
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
          
          // Decode the response data into the MyModel class
          final myModel = MyModel.fromJson(jsonData);
          
          // Do something with the decoded data
          print(myModel.property1);
          print(myModel.property2);
          // ...
        } else {
          // Handle the error or non-200 status code
          print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle any exceptions that occurred
        print('Error: $e');
      }
    }
```